# Redirect loop when MVC client configured to `UseAuthorization` and then `UseAuthentication` instead of the other way around

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've run into an issue which I've now resolved, but I can't understand what exactly is happening.

When setting up an example MVC app to work with IdentityServer4 (I've been following [this tutorial](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/2_interactive_aspnetcore.html)) I'm supposed to ensure the execution of the authentication services on each request by adding `app.UseAuthentication();` in `Configure` function in `Startup` class:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication(); // This bit here is the example of a required change if we want to invoke the interaction between MVC and IdentityServer.
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute()
            .RequireAuthorization();
    });
}
```

What happened initially was that I have accidentally inverted the order of calls to `UseAuthentication()` and `UseAuthorization()`. Instead of:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I had:

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

That results in the MVC application ending up in an infinite redirect loop. Now I know that the order of calls to `UseAuthentication()` and `UseAuthorization()` is important, but what specifically causes the loop? I'm still getting my head around OpenID Connect protocol, so maybe the question is trivial (I hope not).

I've set up a repository with minimum working examples reproducing the issue:

- [branch with working version](https://github.com/mjarosie/IdentityServerRedirectLoop/tree/master)
- [branch with redirect loop version](https://github.com/mjarosie/IdentityServerRedirectLoop/tree/redirect_loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is completely unrelated to OIDC or any other protocol for that matter. This is just the way ASP.NET Core works.

When you do:

1. `app.UseAuthorization();`
2. `app.UseAuthentication();`

You're saying: "first try to authorize the user, and then try to authenticate the request", but you don't know if there's a user or not since you haven't tried to determine the user from the request, so you need to try that first, and you again cannot because you still don't have the authenticated user (and at this point the infinite loop is evident).

On the other hand, when you do:

1. `app.UseAuthentication();`
2. `app.UseAuthorization();`

You're saying: "first try to authenticate the request, and once you have done that, check that the user has the necessary permissions" (even if that just means that there is actually an authenticated user).

**Always** validate the order in which you register your middleware in ASP.NET Core, as that exact same order will be used to process requests. There are many other cases where instead of infinite loops, you'd end up with broken middleware.